# How can I save two or more data in same object[0]

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp

I send date data (which comes from a `CalendarView` object) to the second activity.
This is the first activity:

```
String date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
intent=new Intent(Main3Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("date",date);
```

I get it by converting it to a timestamp in the second activity. So, I can choose a date and I can see it in the second activity, it works fine with 1 date. Here is the second activity:

```
// Create objects
Object[] item;
String s;
DateFormat formatter;
Date date2;
Timestamp timeStampDate;
List<Object[]> data;
long myTime;

myTime11 = sharedPreferences.getLong("long1",0);
s= getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
if(s != null) {
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    try {
        date2 = formatter.parse(s);
        timeStampDate = new Timestamp((date2.getTime()));
        myTime = timeStampDate.getTime();
        editor.putLong("long1",myTime);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    item = new Object[COLUMN_NAMES.length];
    item[0] = myTime11;
    item[1] = 3;
    item[2] = 6;
    item[3] = 9;
    data.add(item);
}
    item = new Object[COLUMN_NAMES.length];
    item[0] = timestamp;
    item[1] = 0;
    item[2] = 0;
    item[3] = 0;
    data.add(item);

    cursor.addAll(data);
    return item;
}
```

However, when I select a second date the first data disappears.

For example, I choose 13/09/2017. Okay, it passes but If I want to pass 14/09/2017 from the CalendarView object with the first activity again, then I can't see 13/09/2017. It changes to 14/09/2017 and I can only see one date which is 14/09/2017. How can I solve this?

Edit: I think it happens because of item[0] = myTime which is just one. If I add two like it, I can pass two dates side by side but I want this to work for all the dates that are selected.

Edit2: I use a library from GitHub. Most of my codes are similar to this: [link](https://github.com/jruesga/timeline-chart-view/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/ruesga/timelinechart/sample/SampleActivity.java). I have just changed specific details.

Edit3: When I added these to solve the problem thanks to suggestions, I get the these errors. How can I solve this?

```
data.add((Object[]) data.get(0)[0]);
data.add((Object[]) data.get(1)[0]);
```

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

```
data.add( 0, (Object[]) item[0]);
data.add( 1, (Object[]) item[0]);
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]

Comment: You can pass an array of dates, instead a single string and parse the single object at a time in second activity.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? like step by step. thanks @procrastinator

Comment: How are you passing two dates? If you pass in `13/09/2017;14/09/2017` for example and then you split in input date at ';' you will need to format each date after the split.

Comment: It's true. I can't pass both of them at the same time. When I pass one of them, It changes with other. I am asking how can I solve this without split? @Sheldon

Comment: I mean split within your code, not the date. I'll type up an answer. You can still pass them as one string variable.

Comment: @Sheldon Thanks, I am waiting.

Comment: What type of variable is data?

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the next time to an `Object` array called `item`, and then putting this in the `List` called `data`.

Depending on when `data` is created, this will cause the problem of the second (and third) date disappearing. If you create `data` as a private field in the code (before the second action runs). Like this:

```
// in the class file:
private List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Then select a few dates with your code and the `CalendarView` object. Then use this in a new action / method when you want to get the dates:

```
public void printDates()
{
    System.out.println(data.get(0)[0]); // gives the first date 2017/09/13
    System.out.println(data.get(1)[0]); // gives the second date 2017/09/14
}
```

Or you can use this to get the specified date from the data List:

```
public Object getLastIthDate(int i)
{
    return data.get(list.size() - i - 1);
}
```

Then somewhere else in the code:

```
System.out.println(getLastIthDate(1)); // gives the second last date that was saved: 2017/09/13
System.out.println(getLastIthDate(0)); // gives the last date that was saved: 2017/09/14
```

Edit: Solution to error from Edit3:
Just add the whole item object to data, like you had in the original code
`data.add(item);` then you will be able to use `time = data.get(0)[0];` somewhere else in the code.

Comment: You need to use the results from that statement. This for example `System.out.println(data.get(0)[0]);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help you are great but is it possible without println? Because I have looked but I could not find where to write it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the dates? You can just access them from the data object with `data.get(0)[0]` when you need them.

Comment: `data.add((Object[]) data.get(0)[0]);
        data.add((Object[]) data.get(1)[0]);
        data.add(item);`

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Do you have any idea for this error?

Comment: The Object[] that you added to data is the first step is empty. So you cant get anything from it.

Comment: However, It shouldn't be empty because I get data thanks to `s= getIntent().getStringExtra("date");` So, When I change `data.add((Object[]) data.get(0)[0]);` to `data.add(item);` , I don't get any error. Although everthing is the same excluding this line, It works in other line code.

Comment: `data.add((Object[]) data.get(0)[0]);` is trying to get the first `Time` value from data and then cast it to an Object[] and add it back to data. I don't think that this is what you want to do. `data.add(item)` will add the new date to the data.

Comment: If you think it isn't working, can you say a code that I can do correctly? I try according to your suggestions but I haven't found solution correctly.